# MySql 'wait_timeout' Global Variable vs Variable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reproduce a connection timeout error by temporarily reducing the "wait_timeout" to 60 seconds instead of the default 28800 seconds.

I added wait_timeout=60 to the my.ini file and restarted MySql.  Unfortunately, I am still not able to reproduce the error condition (unless i want to wait 28800 seconds).

The queries below seem to indicate the "wait_timeout" is set to 60 at the global variable level but still set at 28800 seconds for the regular variable (is that the same as the session variable?).

How can I correct this?  How is the setting in the my.ini getting overwritten?

Thanks for any advice as I am still a bit of a MySql admin noob.  :)

I'm running MySql 5.5.10 on Windows XP.

```
mysql> show variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 60    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From MySQL documentation: [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout):

> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global
>   **wait_timeout** value or from the global **interactive_timeout** value, depending on the 
>   type of client (as defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to 
>   mysql_real_connect()). See also interactive_timeout.

You should also lower interactive_timeout global variable in your ini file.

<strike>Also note that:</strike>

> This timeout applies only to TCP/IP and Unix socket file connections,
>     not to connections made using named pipes, or shared memory.

(As Vladislav pointed the above note should be disregarded, as **[this bug has been fixed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31621)** and the timeout applies to connections with named pipes or shared memory as well, but apparently the docs have not been updated.)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  i modified the interactive_timeout global variable in the my.ini file which did the trick

Comment: That timeout applies only to TCP and Unix domain sockets is outdated info, bug in the documentation. This was fixed back in 2009 (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31621)

Comment: @Vladislav: thnx, I didn't know that.