# MySQL's wait_timeout incorrect in SQLyog

Tags: mysql, configuration, sqlyog

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179747/set-a-persistent-global-mysql-parameter), I set the following MySQL parameter in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini` (the equivalent of Linux's `my.cfg`):

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout=2147483
```

After restarting Windows I used [SQLyog](https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/) to see the effect:

- `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'` gave a result of   `28800`
- `SHOW GLOBAL  VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'` gave a result of `2147483`

How come? I thought the global parameters are used as the default for each new session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonus answer: I've gone through the source code of sqlYog.

It's a `feature`: if the timeout setting `> 28800`, it is hardcoded
to change the session timeout to 28800 in `CommonHelper.cpp`.

```
3314   //Session wait_timeout3315   timeout = conn->m_strwaittimeout.GetAsUInt32();
3316 
3317   if(timeout > 28800 || timeout <= 0)
3318     conn->m_strwaittimeout.SetAs("28800");
3319 
3320   strtimeout.Sprintf("/*!40101 set @@session.wait_timeout=%s */", conn->m_strwaittimeout.GetString());
3321   mysql_options(*pmysql, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, strtimeout.GetString());
```

This explains what you are seeing.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Eljakim, I'm going to change the question just so this is the answer and accept it. you may wish to remove your other answer as it will become irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout
for more information.

The answer at [MySql 'wait_timeout' Global Variable vs Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838692/mysql-wait-timeout-global-variable-vs-variable) may also help you.

Basically, this is the important bit:

> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from
>   the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout
>   value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the
>   CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to mysql_real_connect()). See also
>   interactive_timeout.

Comment: Placed both `wait_timeout=2147483` and `interactive_timeout=2147483` under `[mysqld]` - it did not help

Comment: Are you certain that SQLyog is not the issue? On the screen where you define the connection you can specify session timeout values.